# pandas merge with conditionnal aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to merge two dataframe based on a composed key. The second dataframe have duplicated rows considering the key. Note that the key is not unique in the first dataframe too because there is in fact other many columns in real data. I need to merge with aggregated(product) values  on second dataframe but with a condition on dates. The rows to aggregate should have a date lower than the date of the row from the first data frame.

Here is an example :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': ['Code1', 'Code1', 'Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3', 'Code4'],
    'SG': ['SG1', 'SG1', 'SG1', 'SG2', 'SG3', 'SG3'],
    'Date':
    ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-01']
})



print(df1)
    Code   SG        Date
0  Code1  SG1  2020-02-01
1  Code1  SG1  2020-02-01
2  Code1  SG1  2020-03-01
3  Code2  SG2  2020-01-01
4  Code3  SG3  2020-02-01
5  Code4  SG3  2020-02-01

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': ['Code1', 'Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3'],
    'SG': ['SG1', 'SG1', 'SG2', 'SG3'],
    'Date': ["2019-01-01", "2020-02-25", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-25"],
    'Coef': [0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3]
})

print(df2)

    Code   SG        Date  Coef
0  Code1  SG1  2019-01-01   0.5
1  Code1  SG1  2020-02-25   0.7
2  Code2  SG2  2020-01-13   0.3
3  Code3  SG3  2020-01-25   0.3
```

I want the following result : Line two has aggregated coef 0.5x0.7 =0.35 as all df2.Date for corresponding key are lower than df1.Date

```
    Code   SG        Date  Coef
0  Code1  SG1  2020-02-01  0.50
1  Code1  SG1  2020-02-01  0.50
2  Code1  SG1  2020-03-01  0.35
3  Code2  SG2  2020-01-01   NaN
4  Code3  SG3  2020-02-01  0.30
5  Code4  SG3  2020-02-01   NaN
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: what is the logic behind `Code1  SG1  2020-03-01  0.35` for 2nd row, i dont see it in the question body

Comment: @anky, It is a multiplication base and key (Code1, SG1) are the two row both dates are lower than the date in my first dataframe row – codesensei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally got it!

## Merging (LEFT JOIN) by Code and SG

```
df_group = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['Code','SG'], how='left', suffixes=('','_result'))
```

## Creating a filter for lower dates

```
df_group['lower_date_mask'] = df_group['Date_result'] <= df_group['Date']
```

## Filtering the Coef column with NaNs.

```
df_group.loc[df_group['lower_date_mask'] == False,'lower_date_mask'] = np.nan
df_group['Coef'] = df_group['Coef'] * df_group['lower_date_mask']
```

## We assign infinite to True values here just to avoid Pandas bug when executing the `.prod()` function with NaNs

```
df_group.loc[df_group['lower_date_mask'] == 1.0,'lower_date_mask'] = np.inf
```

Github issue about the aggregation functions with nan: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20824

## Aggregating by .prod()

```
df_group = df_group.groupby(['Code','SG','Date']).prod()
```

## Creating final dataframe

```
df_group.reset_index(inplace = True)
df_group.loc[df_group['lower_date_mask'] == 1.0,'Coef'] = np.nan
df_group.drop(columns = ['lower_date_mask'],inplace = True)
```

## Final output

```
    Code    SG  Date    Coef
    0   Code1   SG1 2020-02-01  0.50
    1   Code1   SG1 2020-03-01  0.35
    2   Code2   SG2 2020-01-01  NaN
    3   Code3   SG3 2020-02-01  0.30
    4   Code4   SG3 2020-02-01  NaN
```

It is worth saying that you can achieve this with the `.apply()` function, however, this would slow you down if your DataFrame grow bigger.

Hope I could help! It took me literally two hours to think this code through!

**EDIT**:

As mentioned by @codesensei, his database has other columns that make the combination `['Code','SG','Date']` not unique. In that case, there are two possible ways to deal with that. First, if there are other columns in df1 or df2 that make the combination unique, just add them in the grouping, like the following:

```
df_group = df_group.groupby(['Code','SG','Date','column_of_interest']).prod()
```

Second, if it's easier to make the combination unique by some sort of ID, let's say the index of df1, you can do:

```
df1.reset_index(inplace = True)
# merge dataframes and follow the other steps as stated earlier in this answer
df_group = df_group.groupby(['Code','SG','Date','index']).prod()
```

If you want, you can rename the 'index' to something else, just to make it more explicit.

Hope I could help!

Comment: the logic is the following :
For each row in DF1 we search on corresponding key ('Code', 'SG') in DF2 to got and subset dataframe RESULT. Then we have to filter on RESULT.date <= DF1.date and we aggregate all corresponding coef. Then merge.
For the tird line, the date in df2 for the corresponding key is after, and for the last line there is no corresponding key. For the fist line only one row meets date condition and for second line, there is two rows which respect the conditions.

Comment: This is a great and inspiring solution. Good job. But it is not totally correct. There is one adjustment to do in your code to solve the problem. It is this instruction **df_group = df_group.groupby(['Code','SG','Date']).prod()**. In fact the df1 dataframe is a hugue table of transactions with many other columns. So the triplet *(Code,SG,Date) is not unique. You have to find another key for the grouping. I suggest to keep a copy of initial indexes in frame df1 and use it for the grouping.

Comment: If that is the case, please edit your question and post the entire problem statement. It is hard to help if we are not aware of the problem details.

Comment: I have edited my question to be most explicit as possible. But you almost solve the problem. I just added *df1['copy_idx'] = df1.index* and ther groupby *['Code','SG','Date','copy_idx']*